# Difference between Get<T> and Load<T>

Tags: nhibernate

What's the difference between `Get<T>(object id)` and `Load<T>(object id)`?  The documentation pretty much reads the same.  Also, if it matters, in what cases should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [reference provided by Brian](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx) explains it quite clearly. However, the **main** difference is that `Load` *doesn't* hit the database to check and load the entity you require, since it assumes you know the entity exists. The object returned by `Load` is some kind of proxy that lazily fetches the real data when required or throws an exception if the entity is not found.

Recap:

- `Load` should be used when you know for sure that an entity with a certain ID exists. The call does not result in a database hit (and thus can be optimized away by NHibernate in certain cases). Beware of the exception that may be raised when the object is accessed if the entity instance doesn't exist in the DB.
- `Get` hits the database or session cache to retrieve the entity data. If the entity exists it is returned, otherwise `null` will be returned. This is the safest way to determine whether an entity with a certain ID exists or not. If you're not sure what to use, use `Get`.

Comment: Great answer. There are some details that might be important in some cases: AFAIK, `Load` does hit the database if lazy loading for the specific entity is turned off. `Load` does not return a proxy if the entity in the cache is not a proxy (while `Get` returns a proxy if it found a proxy in the cache).

Answer (score 11):

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx

Get will return null if the object requested doesn't exist. Load will throw an exception if the object requested doesn't exist. Otherwise, they function exactly the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: It may be clearer to state that it (Load()) will return a proxy (if not found) that will then throw an exception (probably a null reference) if you try to do anything with it.

Comment: @JasonCoder the exception thrown is an `ObjectNotFoundException` specifically. But what you note is indeed correct and important. It means that wrapping a `Load` in `try/catch` is pointless for example.

Answer (score 4):

Load is the optimized way in some cases. Let's think of a Customer, Order relationship and assume that we have an Orders table with CustomerId as the foreign key.

```
var order = new Order {OrderDate = Datetime.Now };
order.Customer = session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
session.Save(order);
```

Although we only need the customerId to persist the order object, above code block will first select the customer with that customerId from Customers table then  hit the database again to insert the order for that customer.

But if we used :

```
order.Customer = session.Load<Customer>(customerId);
```

only the insert statement with that customerId will be executed. Load is the appropriate way in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Get will return Null if the object doesn't exist whereas Load will not return Null - it either returns an object or throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have `Customer` and `Order` tables. `Order` has a foreign key to `Customer`.
You want to create an order for the customer. In this scenario, you are certain that the customer exists on the database, and you don't need actually loading the customer from the database.

Use `load()` to create a proxy class of customer for the order to use, then set the foreign key and save, as follows:

```
Customer customer = session.load<Customer>(id);
Order order = new Order

{
Name = textBoxName.Text,
Type = TextBoxType.Text,
Price= Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text),
Customer = customer
};
```